# C++ Templated fields of a class

Tags: templates, c++11

I am having issues implementing templated fields inside a class, i.e. the class itself is not templated, but one of its data members is. So I have this (I am implementing the heap data structure by the way):

```
template <class HeapItem>
class HeapNode
{
    private:
        HeapItem* m_item;
    public:
        HeapNode(HeapItem*);
        ~HeapNode()
        HeapItem getItem();
};
```

And in the .cpp (the above was .h) file:

```
template <class HeapItem>
HeapNode<HeapItem>::HeapNode () {...}

//Other functions the exact same syntax.
// ...
```

I skipped the declaration and definition for the other functions, because this was mainly just to show the HeapNode class. Now these HeapNode objects will be used inside the heap.

```
template <class HeapItem>
class Heap
{
    private:
        HeapNode<HeapItem>* m_top;
    public:
        void add(HeapItem*);
};
```

And in the .cpp file:

```
template <class HeapItem>
void Heap::add ( HeapItem* item )
{
    m_top = new HeapNode<HeapItem>(item);
}
```

Again, I omitted some functions and their definitions for clarity of what exactly it is I am doing. I have all the classes (obviously not HeapItem) in my own namespaces, so namespace issues shouldn't be occurring. And Heap::add is a temporary stub function to test it out.

Naturally I wouldn't be posting this unless there was an issue with it, so apparently there is. G++ (gnu) is complaining:

```
 // Inside the main function.
 //Foobar is a custom class.
 //This line alone works just fine.
Heap<Foobar> myheap();
 // This line is what causes the error.
myheap.add(new Foobar(842));

Which yields this error:

error: request for member 'add' in 'myheap', which is of non-class type 'Heap<Foobar>()'.
```

Thanks, Steven.

Comment: Note: I compiled each class individually and it is ONLY the main class that is erroring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Heap<Foobar> myheap();
```

Oops, you declared a function named `myheap`, not an object.  This is the [Most Vexing Parse](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/fn-decl-vs-obj-instantiation.html).  Try just:

```
Heap<Foobar> myheap;
```

Comment: I'm just getting back into c++, and I thought this was how one declares an instance of a class.

Answer (score 1):

You need: `m_top = new HeapNode<HeapItem>(item);`

Also, replace `Heap<Foobar> myheap();` with `Heap<Foobar> myheap;`. I'll leave it to you to figure out why (tip: you're not the first one to have this problem).

Comment: I accidentally made a typo in my question, I have this in my actual file, I'll fix real quick.